# $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is not always a complete space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

It is fairly easy to prove that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is a complete space with d(x,y)=|x-y|:

1. Take a Cauchy sequence and prove it is bounded.
2. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass, every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence. Let $\ell$ be this limit.
3. Show that the Cauchy sequence converges towards $\ell$, using the triangular inequality, the fact that it is Cauchy, and the fact that it has a convergent subsequence.

I also know $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is not a complete space with $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$.

What I do not understand is why the previous proof does not work here. In other words, where does the explicit expression of $d(x,y)$ come into account in the proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second step fails: the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem doesn’t hold for the arctangent metric $d$. For instance, the sequence of positive integers is bounded in the metric $d$ but has no convergent subsequence. It’s important to realize here that the notion of boundedness that’s required is boundedness in the metric being used.

Comment: But the Cauchy sequence remains bounded right? Otherwise step 1 would already fail.

Comment: @Kuifje: Yes, that’s correct. In any metric space a Cauchy sequence is bounded with respect to the metric.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: I understand that the sequence of positive integers has no convergent subsequence with the $d$ metric, but in a more general perspective, how can we determine if the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem holds or not (given a metric)? If the Cauchy sequence is bounded in the metric being used, why would it fail?

Comment: @Kuifje: In general you should assume that the B-W theorem does not hold. I’m not sure what *it* refers to in your last question.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Thanks. (Just to be clear $it$ referred to B-W).

Comment: @Kuifje: You’re welcome. (I thought that it probably did, but I wanted to be sure.)